# Loading dynamically created files with XNA

Tags: xna-4.0, loading, file

I'm trying to implement a structured save/load functionality so if the user saves, it will take up one of 10 slots, and if the user loads, they would select one of these slots.

To do this, I need the game to load files from a predefined location, but I can't seem to find a good way to do this. I tried using TitleContainer, but this requires the files to be explicitly added to the project and their properties changed to copy to the output directory in the bin. I've also looked at User data loading, but all the examples I can find are for asynchronous file loading where the user selects a file.

Is there any way to load dynamically created files from a fixed location with XNA, such as save files?

Comment: Is this specific to the console or the phone? Other wise use the standard .net IO library.

Comment: I'm actually using the standard FileStream right now. I still have to add things explicitly to the project and set it to copy to the output bin folder.